# Memory Overflow error for negative numbers - binary addition

Tags: binary, bit-manipulation, addition

The below program binary addition on two integers and works fine for positive numbers, but causes overflow for negative numbers. (For e.g. inputs like 1,-1 fail). Last I checked It is happening because the carry overflows beyond the int capacity. How do I correct this?

```
public int getSum(int a, int b) {
        StringBuilder res = new StringBuilder();
        int carry = 0;
        while (a != 0 || b != 0 || carry != 0) {
            int d = (a&1) ^ (b&1) ^ carry;
            carry = ((a&1)&carry) | ((b&1)&carry) | ((a&1)&(b&1));
            res.append(d);
            a >>= 1;
            b >>= 1;
        }
        res.reverse();
        return Integer.parseInt(res.toString(),2);
    }
```

Comment: Digging further, I now understand that by using the signed right shift operation >>, I perpetuate the signed bit and the number actually never becomes zero. When I changed the >> operation to >>> , it finally gave me the exception I was expecting  : Using string for these problems doesn't seem correct - because the overflow carry bit is not thrown away but appended to string. So when I convert this back to integer, it throws the NumberFormatException.

Comment: :java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "100000000000000000000000000000000" under radix 2
  at line 67, java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString